# Azure DevOps Using Taskgroup in YAML Build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've created a Task group to encapsulate some functionality.
If I use a regular build, I can add the task group through the normal wizard.

Unfortunately, I need to use the task group inside a YAML build. I can't view the YAML of the "old" build to view how this should gonna happen.

The things I've tried:

```
  - task: TaskGroupName@1
    displayName: 'RunTests' 
    inputs:
      TestConfiguration: 'some.xml'
      TestCaseFilter: $(TestCaseFilter)
      UnitTestFolders: $(UnitTestFolders)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups), Task groups are not supported in the YAML pipelines.

Instead, in that case you can use [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#step-templates).

Documentation for templates: [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass parameter 'objects' into a template YAML file to pretty much do what you want; the only tricky bit I found was to have multiple properties per instance parameter 'object' and using the new template `{{ each }}` expression to iterate over them.

Below is how I constructed my yaml files for this solution:

```
azure_pipelines.yml

pool:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands:
  - npm
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest

steps:
- template: azure_webapp_template.yml
  parameters:
    webapps:
    - name: Customer 1
      url: customer1.azurewebsites.net
    - name: Customer 2
      url: customer2.azurewebsites.net
    - name: Customer 3
      url: customer3.azurewebsites.net
    - name: Customer 4
      url: customer4.azurewebsites.net
```

As you can see above, we are creating an object `webapps` and then we have some nested properties for each 'webapp'.

Then in our 'template' we can iterate over each of the objects in the `webapps` parameter and expand the property in our iterated tasks.

```
azure_webapp_template.yml

# Proving ability to loop over params a number of times

parameters:
- name: 'webapps'
  type: object
  default: {}

steps:
- ${{ each webapp in parameters.webapps }}:

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Task Group Test 1 ${{webapp.name}}'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host "Name: ${{webapp.name}} with url ${{webapp.url}}"
      failOnStderr: true
      workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Task Group Test 2 ${{webapp.name}}'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host "Name: ${{webapp.name}} with url ${{webapp.url}}"
      failOnStderr: true
      workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```